# Trying to remove all numbers from a string in C

Tags: c, string, char

I'm trying to take all of the numbers out of a string (char*)...

Here's what I have right now:

```
    // Take numbers out of username if they exist - don't care about these
    char * newStr;
    strtoul(user, &newStr, 10);
    user = newStr;
```

My understanding is that strtoul is supposed to convert a string to an unsigned long.  The characters that are not numbers are put into the passed in pointer (the 2nd arg).  When i reassign user to newStr and print it, the string remains unchanged. Why is this? Does anyone know of a better method?

From the documentation example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
char str[30] = "2030300 This is test";
char *ptr;
long ret;

ret = strtoul(str, &ptr, 10);
printf("The number(unsigned long integer) is %lu\n", ret);
printf("String part is |%s|", ptr);

return(0);
}
```

Let us compile and run the above program, this will produce the following result:

```
The number(unsigned long integer) is 2030300
String part is | This is test|
```

Comment: That is not what the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtoul/) says at all.

Comment: *"My understanding is that strtoul is supposed to convert a string to an unsigned long. The characters that are not numbers are put into the passed in pointer (2nd arg)."*  Your understanding is ***still*** wrong.

Comment: @abelenky It seems thats exactly whats happening in the example from the documentation. ptr contains the string part. So by reassigning the original string pointer to the ptr containing the string part, how is this not  removing the numbers?

Comment: Try a test with `"123 MickeyMouse 456"`.  The return value will be 123, and the `ptr` part will be `" MickeyMouse 456"`.  Numbers were not removed.

Comment: @abelenky So it's only the first numbers that appear in the string. ok. Do you know of a working method to remove all numbers from a string?

Comment: use `strtok` and skip tokens which are numbers (e.g. you could start overwriting your string at the point where a number is found) - you'd still need to handle your delimiters correctly this way though...

Comment: @BeyelerStudios:  ***Never*** use `strtok`.  It is hopelessly broken.  If you must, you can use `strtok_r`.   But anytime you're looking at any version of `strtok`, you should begin to question your life-choices.

Comment: @abelenky weirdly that happens to me every time I use C

Comment: I want to reinforce abelenky's mention: `strtok` is painful - I mistook it's signature for a simple tokenizer (returning the next token's end position) which would make it valid for your use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char* RemoveDigits(char* input)
{
    char* dest = input;
    char* src = input;

    while(*src)
    {
        if (isdigit(*src)) { src++; continue; }
        *dest++ = *src++;
    }
    *dest = '\0';
    return input;
}
```

**Test:**

```
int main(void)
{
    char inText[] = "123 Mickey 456";
    printf("The result is %s\n", RemoveDigits(inText));
    // Expected Output: " Mickey "
}
```

The numbers were removed.

Comment: Moral of the story:  Much of the time there is *not* a `stdlib` method to call.  You have to actually write code. *(that is the job of a programmer)*

Answer (score 1):

Here is a C program to remove digits from a string without using inbuilt functions. The string is shifted left to overwrite the digits:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char a[] = "stack123overflow";
  int i, j;

  for (i = 0; a[i] != '\0'; i ++) {
    if (a[i] == '0' || a[i] == '1' || a[i] == '2' || a[i] == '3' || a[i] == '4' || a[i] == '5' || a[i] == '6' || a[i] == '7' || a[i] == '8' || a[i] == '9') {
      for (j = i; a[j] != '\0'; j ++)
        a[j] = a[j + 1];

      i--;
    }
  }

  printf("%s", a);
  return 0;
}
```

Example of execution:

```
$ gcc shift_str.c -o shift_str
$ ./shift_str
stackoverflow
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`strtoul()` does not extract all numbers from string, it just trying to covert string to number and convertion stops when non digit is find. So if your string starts from number `strtoul()` works as you expect, but if string starts from letters, `strtoul()` stops at the first symbol. To solve your task in simple way you should copy all non-digits to other string, that will be a result.

Comment: Ok, I understand now.  Do you know of a working method I can use to accomplish this?

Comment: I provided a link to a solution(that copies what you need to a new buffer) in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that strtoul is converting characters at the beginning of the string into an unsigned long.   Once it encounters non-numeric digits, it stops.

The second parameter is a pointer into the original character buffer, pointing at the first non-numeric character.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtoul/

**Parameter 2** : *Reference to an object of type char*, whose value is set by the function to the next character in str after the numerical value.*

So, if you tried to run the function on "123abc567efg" the returned value would be 123.   The original string buffer would still be "123abc567efg" with the second parameter now pointing at the character 'a' in that buffer.   That is, the pointer (ptr) will have a value 3 greater than original buffer pointer (str).   Printing the string ptr, would give you "abc567efg" as it simply points back into the original buffer.

To actually remove ALL the digits from the string in C you would need to do something similar to this answer : [Removing spaces and special characters from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15444567/removing-spaces-and-special-characters-from-string)

You build your allowable function to return false on 0-9 and true otherwise.  Loop through and copy out digits to a new buffer.