# How to remove a digit from a String in C

Tags: c, string, digits

I don't have any idea to remove digits from a string. My first ides was to use a `for`-loop to go through the string. With the function `is_digit` you can check if it's a digit. But when I identify that what should I do now or somebody have a better way to remove digits.

```
#include "base.h"

bool is_digit(char c) {
    return c >= ’0’ && c <= ’9’;
}
    
char *remove_digits(char *s) {
     // to do
}

void test(void) {
    test_equal_s(remove_digits(""), "");
    test_equal_s(remove_digits("x"), "x");
    test_equal_s(remove_digits("11"), "");
    test_equal_s(remove_digits("11x"), "x");
    test_equal_s(remove_digits("x11"), "x");
    test_equal_s(remove_digits("x11x"), "xx");
    test_equal_s(remove_digits("1a2b3c4"), "abc");
}

int main(void) {
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to remove all numbers from a string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28353173/trying-to-remove-all-numbers-from-a-string-in-c)

Comment: `is_digit()` is merely reinventing [standard C's `isdigit()`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.4.1.5).

Comment: @TruVortex_07 it's not quite the same, the dup is for *removing* characters, in this case we can't do that because the arguments are string literals.

Answer (score 2):

If you want do use your own algorithm you can use do something like this:

```
#include <string.h> // for strlen
```

```
char *remove_digits(char *s)
{
    char *new_s = malloc(strlen(s) + 1); // allocate memory for the new string
    if (new_s == NULL)
    {
        return new_s; // return NULL if malloc fails
    }
    char *new_s_begin = new_s; // pointer to keep at the beggining of the new string
    while (*s) // while the string doesn't reach the null byte
    {
        if (!is_digit((unsigned char)*s)) // if the character it is not a digit...
        {
            *new_s++ = *s; // copy it to the new string
        }
        s++; // next character
    }
    *new_s = 0; // null terminate string
    return new_s_begin; // return a pointer to the beginning of the new string
}
```

Comment: The user is passing in a string constant which cannot be modified without causing undefined behavior.

Comment: @BillLynch I didn't realize that at first, just fixed it, thks.

Answer (score 1):

Since the string you'll have to pass might be different from the original, first thing you make a copy.

```
char* remove_digits(char* s) {
    char *copy;

    // reserve space for string and its terminating zero
    copy = malloc(strlen(s)+1);
    // Never trust malloc to return correctly
    if (NULL == copy) {
        return NULL;
    }

    // Then the idea is to copy only the non-digits.

    char *sp;     // Source pointer
    char *dp = copy;  // Destination pointer

    for (sp = s; *sp; sp++) {
        if (!is_digit(*sp)) {
            *(dp++) = *sp;
        }
    }

    // At the end, "copy" is not yet a valid C string because it
    // need to be zero- terminated, so:

    *(dp) = 0x0;

    return copy;
}
```

Comment: @chqrlie aargh, you're right! Thanks! Edited answer.

Comment: Why do I have these errors?

Altklausur_1.c: In function 'is_digit':
Altklausur_1.c:5:13: error: stray '\342' in program
    5 | return c >= Ô <= Ô             ^
Altklausur_1.c:5:14: error: stray '\200' in program
    5 | return c >= Ôm <= Ô
Altklausur_1.c:5:15: error: stray '\231' in program
    5 | return c >= Ô01;31mm0Ô <= Ô
Altklausur_1.c:5:17: error: stray '\342' in program
    5 | return c >= Ô01;31mÔ <= Ô
Altklausur_1.c:5:18: error: stray '\200' in program
    5 | return c >= Ô01;31mm <= Ô
Altklausur_1.c:5:19: error: stray '\231' in program
make: *** [Altklausur_1] Error 1

Comment: You used UTF8 quotes in your code. Use standard quotes: 'c', not ??c??.